# Теоретический вопрос про text-transform

Tags: шрифты, текст

Скажите, лучше просто писать через caps lock или же задавать конкретному элементу text-transform: uppercase?
 И так же вопрос про теги b, i, u и тд. Лучше прописывать их в html или же в css с помощью font-style?

Comment: Зависит от ситуации

Comment: Это понятно, в вёрстке всё всегда зависит от ситуации) Но как по умолчанию это положено делать или как будет легче для той же скорости загрузки?